MySQL - error-log server-side error messages sent to client programs - ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.no_such_table' doesn't exist
I have a import processing application that collects logs from multiple computers in multiple locations.
Each client executes a 4 server store procedures. These stored procedures call stored functions and some of those stored functions call another layer of stored functions.
My error handling works great using RESIGNAL to pass error information up the top stored procedures. Since no one is sitting in front of the computer running the import process it something happens to blow I want to write the error information gathered from:
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 e1 = MYSQL_ERRNO, e2 = MESSAGE_TEXT, e3 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, e4 = SCHEMA_NAME, e5 = CATALOG_NAME;

into a text log file. I can not write it to MySQL import_error table due to TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK.
I thought it would be simple to have error information inserted into the server. All night and I can't figure it out!
- General and Slow logging.
log-output=FILE
general-log=1
general_log_file="general.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="slow-query.log"
long_query_time=20
- Error Logging.
log-error="error.log"
log-error-services='log_filter_internal;log_sink_syseventlog'
log-error-suppression-list=''
log-error-verbosity=3
log_timestamps = UTC

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/error-log.html
Example server-side error message sent to client programs, as displayed by the mysql client:
mysql> SELECT * FROM no_such_table;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.no_such_table' doesn't exist

Each server error message includes an error code, SQLSTATE value, and message string, as described in Error Message Sources and Elements. These elements are available as described in Error Information Interfaces.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/error-log.html
What am I missing?

It is not straightforward in mysql to write into a text file. Did you try using a non-transactional table that is not affected by rollback for logging? Try myisam or csv table engine. The latter will result in a text file

@Shadow I just got back in office and tested with import_error table as MyISAM. You are my new Best Friend! Oracle has been my development database for decades and this is first big project in MySQL. This is a much better solution than the server error-log! Next time I will not wait as long to post a question to stackoverflow. Thank you Shadow!

If anyone is looking to do the same with MariaDB, the sql_error_log plugin has a sql_error_log_warnings=1 setting that can be set.
